# Is ssh pass secure?

Tags: linux, bash, ssh, sshpass

I'm writing a script to automate running a specific command across multiple Linux systems. I am going to use something like:

```
read -s "Enter password" ANS
sshpass -p $ANS ssh server "some command"
```

Is there going to be a security concern on this?

Comment: The password will show up in `ps` output.

Comment: Don't forget to quote variables: `-p "$ANS"`.

Comment: SO is for programming questions, not questions about using or configuring Linux and its applications. SuperUser.com or unix.stackexchange.com would be better places for questions like this.

Comment: `read -s "Enter password" SSHPASS; export SSHPASS; sshpass -e ssh server "some command"; unset SSHPASS`?

Comment: Why make your script prompt for the password when `ssh` is perfectly capable of doing so itself, and more securely than your script can?

Comment: If you are serious about automation, you'll configure `ssh` to use private key authentication instead of requiring passwords.

Comment: @chepner - the script intiates multiple parallel background ssh connections and the prompts from ssh will be useles..

Comment: @AnupAdhikari Like I said, use private key authentication.

Answer (score 0):

Your password, and any other command line arguments, will be visible to anyone else on the system using the ps command. A better alternative would be to use SSH key based login? [Official Doc](https://www.ssh.com/ssh/key/)

Comment: This should be a comment, it doesn't answer the question.

Comment: This was the output in ps command "sshpass -p zzzzzzzzzzzz ssh -oConnectTimeout=7 ..." so looks like password is not displayed

Answer (score 0):

The sshpass [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sshpass) has a whole section on the security implications.

> Users of sshpass are encouraged to use one of the other password
>   passing techniques, which are all more secure.
>
> In particular, people writing programs that are meant to communicate
>   the password programatically are encouraged to use an anonymous pipe
>   and pass the pipe's reading end to sshpass using the -d option.

So, if you must pass a password, they encourage the use of an anonymous pipe. You could also save the password to a file and use the `-f` flag instead.

If you're interested in security, key-based authentication is the best option. Sometimes this isn't reasonable as your target(s) has a lack of extra non-volatile memory to store a public key, but you *should* try to set up key-based auth if you can.